# categories links to 404 page not found

Tags: php, magento

Magento all categories links on frontend goes to 404 page not found. What database table is responsabile for that? Or i should set something in admin?
The reindex url catalog is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be issue is with category url suffix which was expecting a .html suffix but the links were giving blank. Change

`Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations -> category suffix`

from ".html" to "" (blank) and It works fine.